# what is the difference between the available postgresql libraries in R?

Tags: r, postgresql, rpostgresql

I am using `postgresql` for some of my analysis and so far in R I've used the `RPostgreSQL` library.

After a recent check I discovered that

- while still on CRAN, the sources are in the process of been evicted as part of the changes in google.code. Last update sometime 2014 (but the CRAN version is 3 years old).
- I couldn't find an indication of where the "official" source library is going to be (on the other hand on github there are various versions but it is difficult to understand which one is the "official" one).
- While browsing I discovered a `RPostgres` package by Hadley Wickham (no less!). It is described as being faster that `RPostgreSQL`, on the other hand it doesn't seem as mature. It is comforting that the latest update has been done in Feb. 2015.

My research on google for "GitHub rpostgresql tomoaki" wasn't helpful: there are loads of people that have copied the sources from google code onto GitHub and I couldn't find Tomoaki's page.

Does anybody know if:

- `RPostgreSQL` is still actively maintained?
- Where the official sources are going to be located?

Also, what are the differences between `RPostgres` and `RPostgreSQL`?

Comment: 1) It's a *package* [in R terms a library is something else entirely], 2) questions asking for differences between pkgs often descend into opinionated answers and counter answers. 3) As Dirk mention, CRAN really is the location of the sources for the pkg; development may well happen elsewhere, but unless you want to install unreleased code, CRAN is the place to look. 4) You have the means to install both and compare them in your actual use case. I would suggest doing that would be more profitable that soliciting opinion here. (Hence my vote to close as OT)

Answer (score 3):

Briefly:

1. The [RPostgreSQL package on CRAN](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/packages/RPostgreSQL/index.html) is in fine health.  See for example the [CRAN test result page for it](https://cran.rstudio.com/web/checks/check_results_RPostgreSQL.html) showing no error.
2. The package has transferred, like many others, to GitHub. See [here for the repo](https://github.com/tomoakin/RPostgreSQL). It still looks mostly 'auto-transferred' but [here is a recent commit](https://github.com/tomoakin/RPostgreSQL/commit/35f4d7e4510992bee9b06a886eedac21f8688ebf) by Tomoaki.

Your post is somewhat full of fear, uncertainty and doubt. A little research could have prevented that.

Rest assured that we will not let the package fall to the wayside.

(Disclose: I am a former maintainer and its initial GSoC mentor.)

Comment: and better communication usually prevents fear... Differences with RPostgres??

Comment: to be more specific, it would be nice to have a Readme file in the repo saying: `this is the official repo (etc.)`.  Should I send a pr?

Comment: The official source of the package is the tar.gz on CRAN.

Comment: Dirk you are contradicting yourself!  How on hearth are people supposed to know that there are recent committs if on CRAN you have left the old address? As far as research, try to google (which I did before asking the question) "github rpostgresql tomoaki": there are loads of people that have copied the sources from google code onto github and Tomoaki's page is not in the top 10. Moreover, you have not answered my question (see title): what is the difference between the two packages??

Comment: Dirk: you are behaving as a bully: what is the sense of mentioning "fear uncertain and doubt" in your unhelpful response? Moreover I did not make "statements" I asked advise and guidance (but I did not asked to be bullied)

Comment: @Enzo Dirk is being direct, forthright, robust, but he's not bullying you. He's under no obligation to actually answer your question; if you don't like the answer there are appropriate [so] responses. BTW, FUD is common parlance in tech circles and you could, especially if you have skin in the game, read your question as being less than flattering about one of the packages in question.

Comment: @Gavin according to Dirk I made " unflattering (and plain false) statements". In fact all I've reported in the question is factual. I do not see anything "less than flattering".  I am actually glad that `RPostgreSQL` is progressing, but people should know where the project web page is (URL in CRAN parlance). 2 out of 3 addresses in `RPostgreSQL` URL on CRAN  are either abandoned or "not found" (and the only one working is postgresql.org).

Comment: @Enzo 1) I said "you could read it as", not that you actually had said or meant anything unflattering. There is a presumption that the project is dead / slow in your Answer; at least you could read it that way & one's propensity to do so may increase if you have personal links to the pkg. 2) That the URL is dead is a bug but an understandable one; one could argue that releasing the same pkg but with an updated URL in `DESCRIPTION` is a waste of CRAN's resources (machine & human), so I can understand that minus a new version of the software the maintainer has not updated the CRAN source yet.